# How to use lead() efficiently and return next different value?

Tags: sql, lag, lead

I have a table that records user transactions like this (simplified version) in BigQuery

| user | transaction_date | label | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-10-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 |
| b | 2021-10-31 10:30:00 | y2 | 10 |
| c | 2021-10-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 |
| a | 2021-11-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 |
| a | 2021-12-31 10:30:00 | y2 | 10 |
| b | 2021-11-31 10:30:00 | y3 | 10 |
| c | 2021-11-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 |
| b | 2021-12-31 10:30:00 | y2 | 10 |
| c | 2021-12-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 |

I am interested in information related to cost and current/next label. How can I use LEAD() to return the next different label as label_next?

i.e

| user | transaction_date | label | cost | label_next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-10-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 | y2 |
| b | 2021-10-31 10:30:00 | y2 | 10 | y3 |
| c | 2021-10-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 | y3 |
| a | 2021-11-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 | y2 |
| a | 2021-12-31 10:30:00 | y2 | 10 | y5 |
| b | 2021-11-31 10:30:00 | y3 | 10 | y2 |
| c | 2021-11-31 10:30:00 | y1 | 10 | y3 |
| b | 2021-12-31 10:30:00 | y2 | 10 | null |
| c | 2021-12-31 10:30:00 | y3 | 10 | null |
| a | 2021-12-31 18:30:00 | y5 | 10 | null |

standard LEAD() would return just the next label i.e. for row 1 (user a) would return y1 as the same user is registered with the same label once before being seen with a different label.

I think I have one solution that involves:
grouping by user, label and calculate min and max transaction_date
then use LEAD() to get label_next per grouping
and join that table on the initial table on user and transaction_date inside min and max transaction_date

But is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a conditional aggregation approach here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN LEAD(label) OVER (PARTITION BY user
                                                ORDER BY transaction_date) != label
                         THEN 1 END) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT user, cnt, label
    FROM cte
)

SELECT t1.user, t1.transaction_date, t1.label, t2.label AS label_next
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t2.user = t1.user AND
       t2.cnt = t1.cnt + 1
ORDER BY t1.user, t1.transaction_date;
```

The idea here is to generate a running count, across each record for each user, which increments by 1 every time the label changes.  We use this result to generate (in `cte2`) an intermediate table where, given a count value and user, we can lookup the next different label.  The final left join is where this lookup is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach we can take that doesn't involve lead function is to find the next label for a user where the label value is not matching current label and the transaction date is greater than current date.

edit: edited to fetch next label based on date not on min label.

```
    with temp as (select 'a' user, '2021-10-31 10:30:00' as transaction_date, 'y1' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'a' user, '2021-11-31 10:30:00' as transaction_date, 'y1' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'a' user, '2021-12-31 10:30:00   ' as transaction_date, 'y2' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'a' user, '2021-13-31 20:30:00   ' as transaction_date, 'y5' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'a' user, '2021-14-31 20:30:00   ' as transaction_date, 'y0' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'b' user, '2021-10-31 10:30:00' as transaction_date, 'y2' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'b' user, '2021-11-31 10:30:00' as transaction_date, 'y3' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'b' user, '2021-12-31 10:30:00   ' as transaction_date, 'y2' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'c' user, '2021-10-31 10:30:00' as transaction_date, 'y1' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'c' user, '2021-11-31 10:30:00' as transaction_date, 'y1' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'c' user, '2021-12-31 10:30:00   ' as transaction_date, 'y3' as label, '10' as cost
union all
select 'c' user, '2021-12-31 20:30:00   ' as transaction_date, 'y4' as label, '10' as cost
)
select user, transaction_date, label, cost,  (select label from temp b where b.user = a.user and b.transaction_date = (select min(transaction_date) from temp c where a.label <> c.label and a.user = c.user and c.transaction_date > a.transaction_date)
 ) as label_next
from temp a
```

Comment: The problem with your subquery is that the minimum label is not necessarily the next one on the timeline.  What _might_ work would be to use a limit subquery ordered by time.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I had in mind only the scenarios you mentioned in the question. So, now I have edited the query to fetch the next label based on next upcoming date of changed label, not minimum label itself. Please highlight if any other scenarios are failing

Answer (score 0):

Below might be an another option.

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(labels),
       (SELECT l FROM t.labels WHERE t.label <> l ORDER BY td LIMIT 1) label_next
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(label AS l, transaction_date AS td)) OVER w AS labels
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY transaction_date DESC)
  ) t;
```

###### Query results

[image]